# How to end if statement in vbscript

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

I Don't know how to end this statement. I have looked it up all over and I can't find the answer

```
Option Explicit
Dim objSHL : Set objSHL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim n,i,x

n=15 ' fifteen seconds

For i = 1 To n
   x = objSHL.Popup(""&n&"",1,"Countdown",vbokonly)

   n=n-1
   If n = 0 Then
       y=MsgBox("Oh No",vbokonly,"")
   Else
       If y = vbokonly Then

           Exit For
   End If
```

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers apparently they *"have looked it up all over"*.

Answer (score -1):

```
n=n-1
If n = 0 Then
    y=MsgBox("Oh No",vbokonly,"")
Else
    If y = vbokonly Then

    End If
End If
```

With 2 x `End If`. One `end if` for each *multiline* `if`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Option Explicit
Dim objSHL : Set objSHL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim n,i,x,y

n=15 ' fifteen seconds

For i = 1 To n
   x = objSHL.Popup(""&n&"",1,"Countdown",vbokonly)

   'n=n-1
   If n = 0 Then
       y=MsgBox("Oh No",vbokonly,"")
   Else
       If y = vbokonly Then

           Exit For
       End If
   End If
Next
```

You are missing 1 End if for your "If y = vbokonly..." also the Next at the end of your Code that is closing your For-Loop. 
Also I made a Comment out of your n=n-1, because the Next knows how to count. 
It will cout your i upwards now. 
Also also you have to declare your "y" ;)

Comment: You can also use a single line If statement if there are no Else part. For e.g. `If y = vbokonly Then Exit For` in a single line won't need an EndIf